# wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```
POST https://site.ru/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 ()      jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
```

Возвращает 500. 
В логах

```
[13-Oct-2017 07:13:30 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: fax in /home/s/sakhasqh/site.ru/public_html/wp-content/themes/houzez/inc/widgets/houzez-contact.php on line 40
[13-Oct-2017 07:14:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: fax in /home/s/sakhasqh/site.ru/public_html/wp-content/themes/houzez/inc/widgets/houzez-contact.php on line 40
[13-Oct-2017 07:15:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function houzez_get_terms_array() in /home/s/sakhasqh/site.ru/public_html/wp-content/themes/houzez/framework/functions/property_functions.php:1970
Stack trace:
#0 /home/s/sakhasqh/site.ru/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): houzez_header_map_listings('')
#1 /home/s/sakhasqh/site.ru/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#2 /home/s/sakhasqh/site.ru/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 /home/s/sakhasqh/site.ru/public_html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php(92): do_action('wp_ajax_houzez_...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /home/s/sakhasqh/site.ru/public_html/wp-content/themes/houzez/framework/functions/property_functions.php on line 1970
```

Кусок куда обращается в логах

```
$prop_locations = array();
houzez_get_terms_array( 'property_city', $prop_locations );
```

В общем не понял в чем ошибка. Проблема в картах гугла.

Comment: Пытаюсь запустить карту, не запускается

Comment: Русским же языком написано)) Неизвестная функция `houzez_get_terms_array()` И `fax` Вы тоже не передаете